# Scripting language component for Lazarus

Tags: delphi, scripting, pascal, lazarus

What is the best multiplatfrom scripting language component to embed into lazarus build projects with full support of the GUI.

I have tried "Pascal Script" but it has no sample code or documentation how to use it...

Any idea ?

Comment: If you are ok with delphi, then try this one http://www.paxcompiler.com/ it's very powerful scripting engine works more or less like an added compiler to your application.

Comment: As "www.paxcompiler.com" says, paxcompiler seems to be OK even with Lazarus but how can I use it. There is no installable package for Lazarus in the websitee!

Comment: you can contact the author Alexander - paxscript@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

PascalScript will be available beginning with Lazarus 1.1. See http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Editor_Macros_PascalScript for details.

Comment: @MJ.Ahmadi: You asked for documentation, and this is the information that is publicly available at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Most people seem to use pascalscript. An year ago, people were working to integrate a version into the Lazarus IDE, but I don't know what became of that.

What you mean with "full support of the GUI", then I don't understand. The GUI is native Pascal, so the only way to use it is by something that can call native pascal.

IOW It doesn't matter if the scripting language is pascal syntax based or not, but how it can interface to native Pascal methods, supports its callbacks etc.